# How Use Datasets in MVVM .Net WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I'm developping an application in VB.net and WPF but i can read C# code
Currently we're using CollectionViewSource and directly fill the dataset. But it seems to not being correct for MVVM and i think it's taking us so much time to develop views, events and all data verifications.

See what i've tried without using Commands relay for clicks
My ModelTemplate class is a base class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged :
ViewXaml :

```xml
<Grid x:Name="grid_Granulats">
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_granulats" AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                            EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
              Style="{DynamicResource DataGrid_Selection}"
              MinWidth="350"
              MinHeight="100">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code"
                                Width="auto"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Désignation"
                                Width="auto"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding Designation, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Silo"
                                Width="auto"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding Silo, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stock"
                                Width="auto"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding Stock, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unité"
                                Width="auto"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding Unite, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

View.vb :

```vb
Public Class F_Stocks
    Public myViewModel As New StockViewModel()

    Public Sub New()
        ' Cet appel est requis par le concepteur.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Ajoutez une initialisation quelconque après l'appel InitializeComponent().
        grid_Granulats.DataContext = myViewModel.MatListe
    End Sub

    Public Sub B_Valider_Click()
        Try
            myViewModel.addMat("N035", "Nouveau Code", 5000, 5, "T")
        Catch ex As Exception
            G_Message_Info(UC_Message, Mod_Utilitaires.Type_message.erreur, Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub B_Supprimer_Click()
        Try
            myViewModel.removeMat(datagrid_granulats.SelectedItem)
        Catch ex As Exception
            G_Message_Info(UC_Message, Mod_Utilitaires.Type_message.erreur, Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

And my ViewModel, note that I know the model should be on other class but it's just for example :

```vb
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data
Imports Librairie_Parametres
    
Public Class StockViewModel
    Inherits Model_Template
    
    Public Class MatModel
        Inherits Model_Template
    
        Public Sub New(p_Code As String,
                       p_Designation As String,
                       p_Stock As Double,
                       p_silo As Integer,
                       p_unite As String)
            Code = p_Code
            Designation = p_Designation
            Stock = p_Stock
            Silo = p_silo
            Unite = p_unite
        End Sub
    
        Private m_Code As String
        Public Property Code() As String
            Get
                Return m_Code
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_Code = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Code")
            End Set
        End Property
    
        Private m_Desgination As String
        Public Property Designation() As String
            Get
                Return m_Desgination
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_Desgination = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Designation")
            End Set
        End Property
    
        Private m_Stock As Double
        Public Property Stock() As Double
            Get
                Return m_Stock
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                m_Stock = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Stock")
            End Set
        End Property
    
        Private m_silo As Integer
        Public Property Silo() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_silo
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                m_silo = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Silo")
            End Set
        End Property
    
        Private m_unite As String
        Public Property Unite() As String
            Get
                Return m_unite
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_unite = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Unite")
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    
    Private m_MatListe As ObservableCollection(Of MatModel)
    Public Property MatListe() As ObservableCollection(Of MatModel)
        Get
            Return m_MatListe
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of MatModel))
            m_MatListe = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MatListe")
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Public Sub New()
        MatListe = New ObservableCollection(Of MatModel)
        MatListe.Add(New MatModel("M012", "Premier Produit", 150, 1, "kg"))
        MatListe.Add(New MatModel("M013", "Deuxieme Produit", 400, 2, "T"))
        MatListe.Add(New MatModel("M014", "Troisieme Produit", 500, 3, "kg"))
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub addMat(p_Code As String,
                      p_Designation As String,
                      p_Stock As Double,
                      p_silo As Integer,
                      p_unite As String)
    
        MatListe.Add(New MatModel(p_Code, p_Designation, p_Stock, p_silo, p_unite))
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub removeMat(mat As MatModel)
        MatListe.Remove(mat)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Everything is working but now I want to know how can I generate object to my list from my dataset with filtering ?

I can read C# Code if needed it is just about concept

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I generate object to my list from my dataset with filtering" ? Do you want to apply a filter to your itemsSource ?
Also instead of setting the DataContext with `grid_Granulats.DataContext = myViewModel.MatListe` usually one would set the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel if that's not already the case then you can edit the ItemsSource of the view like this : `ItemsSource="{Binding MatListe}"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.